# domain at one IP address and subdomain at a different IP address

Tags: dns, nameservers, a-records

At the moment, I have the following set up:

A records:

mydomain.com - aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa

subdomain.mydomain.com - aaa.aaa.aaa.aaa

NS records:

mydomain.com - ns.mydomain.com

What I want to do is to keep the subdomain at that IP address and move mydomain.com to a new server (bbb.bbb.bbb.bbb and ns.newserver.com). Is this possible, and what records do I have to add?

Answer (score 8):

You don't need a separate nameserver.

You are free to make as many A records as you like, pointing to as many IP addresses as you like, all on one nameserver.

Comment: Ah, ok. So I change the A-record for the main domain to point to the new server? I always thought you needed to change the nameserver too, to get it to resolve at the new IP address.

Comment: @babbaggeii: Exactly.  No; nameservers simply reply to DNS queries with the host records you configure.

Comment: I have a domain name as www.abcd.com its under a dns. now i need to point www.abcd.com/help to another server. How can i do that?

Comment: You need an HTTP redirector.  Most registrars provide one.

Comment: In Windows you can change hosts file located in "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc"